# Is there a way to trigger spring-elastic-search mapping type when a field value is null by default?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

In our current Spring-data-elasticsearch v.4.0.4 application, we are using @Document on a POJO and we notice that whenever we have a null value field, the field will not have a mapping type in Elasticsearch. Therefore when we run a query and sort on this field, we will have Elasticsearch error `No mapping found for [view_date] in order to sort on`

We tried using the `storeNulValue` option of the `@Field` in v.4.1.0, the field presents in the index.  However, there is still no mapping type for this field in Elasticsearch and we still see the no mapping found error when we sort on this null value field.

Is there a way to trigger the mapping even when a field has null value?

Answer (score 0):

How do you have the mapping for your index created? When creating the mapping with Spring Data Elasticsearch this is done without a special entity and without knowing if a special instance has null valued properties. the `storeNullValue` argument is used then.

The mapping will be automatically created when you use Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories and the index does not yet exist. Or you need to call the `IndexOperations.create()` and `IndexOperations.putMapping()` by yourself.

Comment: We use esOperations.bulkIndex() to index our data.  We have @Document on our POJOs and rely on SDES to automatically create indices with corresponding mapping according to the documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#elasticsearch.repositories.autocreation

Comment: so does the mapping have a field named _view_date_ ? check what the _/indexname/mappings endpoint returns from Elasticsearch

Comment: _/indexname/mappings does not return the mapping type for view_date.  
However, I was able to have the mapping added to ES with `indexOperations.putMapping(indexOperations.createMapping(resourceClass))`
with `@Field (type=Long)` on the view_date field.

Comment: then the index was not initially created by Spring Data Elasticsearch. So when the mapping is added now, your sort should work.

Comment: Yeah.  Looks like having @Document on the entity doesn't guarantee that mapping will be created during indexing.  Something we were relying on based on the Spring ES documentation from the link above.

Comment: The mapping is not created during indexing. The mapping is created, when a Spring Data Elasticsearch repository is initialized, and the index does not yet exist.